# MySQL - SELECT WHERE date < X

Tags: mysql, syntax, date

How do I do this in MySQL?

```
 SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE MyDateCol < TODAY()
```

I googled a lot on the subject and didn't really find anything except "look in the MySQL date ref" which does not explain the above easily enough.

I know I can do the following which is kinda indirect:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE MyDateCol BETWEEN (0000-00-00) AND TODAY()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In MySQL, you have the [`curdate()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curdate) funciton, that will get you the date of today.

So, something like this should do :

```
select *
from your_table
where your_date_column < curdate()
```

Quoting the manual's page of that function :

> Returns the current date as a value in
>   `'YYYY-MM-DD'` or `YYYYMMDD`  format,
>   depending on whether the function is
>   used in a string or numeric context.

And if you want to compare to the current time *(and not only day)*, you can use the [`now()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now) function :

> Returns the current date and time as a
>   value in `'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS'` or
>   `YYYYMMDDHHMMSS.uuuuuu` format

Comment: Regarding the YYYYMMDD numeric format, would 2010-Mar-27 become 20100327 or would it be the decimal added value of 2,040

Comment: I don't have a server on which I can try right now, but considering the manual says YYYYMMDD, I suppose you'd get 20100327, and no kind of the result of an addition -- which would be hard to work with.

Comment: I've verified this with my local MySQL server, it uses numbers like 20100327 which makes it really easy to do comparisons. You can also cast the string date directly to a number to use it for numeric comparison .. `"2010-03-27" => "20100327" => 20100327`

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE MyDateCol < CURDATE()
```

Answer (score 2):

If MySQL supports SYSDATE, you should use that instead of NOW() or CURDATE(), since it's more standard.

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE MyDateCol < SYSDATE;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`NOW()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now) function:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE MyDateCol < NOW()
```